# Create a app by using java script on Android for multiple devices

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have an HTML app which calls some functions from JavaScript files, and the JS files make some AJAX queries and get JSON objects in response.

I have to make a similar app on Android which can be run on multiple devices (Android), by using the same JS files. In other words, I have a JavaScript API, and I have to use this API to make the app on Android.

I have some queries:

1. Would it be feasible by using WebView (considering it's a big app not a small app)?
2. Should I use PhoneGap?

Please let me know how could I do this and welcome to some more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Answers :

1. Yes , Using Webview you can build application using HTML + Java Script
2. Its depend upon you applications functionality and usage of your application. If you want to make your app Cross Platform like (Android , IOS ) You should try out Phonegap.